# Unable to append rows starting with column A everytime

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-api-php-client

I am trying to append some values in spreadsheet using google api php client.

I have successfully added data in the sheet but every time I run the code, it start appending values from column where the previous ended in the next row.

I am trying to append values in new row every time but it must start from column A.

Here is my code.

```
$client  = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Sheets( $client );

$spreadsheetId = 'my-spreadsheet-id';
$range         = 'sheet1';

$values = array(
    array( "Item", "Cost", "Stocked", '', '', "Ship Date" )
);

$body   = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange( array( 'values' => 
$values, 'majorDimension' => 'ROWS', 'range' => 'sheet1' ) );

$params = array( 'valueInputOption' => 'USER_ENTERED', 
'insertDataOption' => 'INSERT_ROWS' );

$service->spreadsheets_values->append( $spreadsheetId, $range, 
$body, $params );
```

Now, when I run this code it appends "Item" on column A of a new row and "Ship Date" on column F.
This is correct.

But when I run the same code again, it appends the data in new row but starts with Column F and ends with column K.

I want the next time also the data should start appending from column A and ends on column F.

Please help me achieve this, I have read its documentation but couldn't make it work, tried to find answer on internet on various website but was not able to make it work.
Can anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

I found a resolution after going deep inside the code.

If anyone looking for the same then the solution for me is I need to change the range.
First get all the values and find the number of rows present in the sheet then you can append blank values in the sheet starting with new row and column A

Here is my updated code for range:

```
$range      = 'sheet1!A1:Z';
$response   = $service->spreadsheets_values->get( $spreadsheetId, $range );
$get_values = $response->getValues();
$row        = count( $get_values ) + 1;// Plus 1 for new row.

$range = 'sheet1!A' . $row . ':Z' . $row;
```

Use this range in the code which works fine.

Comment: Defining a range including columns is the key. FWIW, I _think_ the logic is this. [_"The body of the update request must be a ValueRange object"_](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#appending_values); [_"The input range is used to search for existing data and find a "table" within that range. Values are appended to the next row of the table, **starting with the first column of the table.**"_](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#appending_values). Google found the last table ended in row F - so it appended the next row starting at Column F.

Comment: Hi,
I already gone through the doc before posting question here.
Google will append the new data in next row starting with column A every time if there is no blank/space values.

This issue arises only when there is blank/space values.

That's why I was not able to find any solution in the doc or anywhere else. But getting data and then calculating rows worked for me.

However, this also has it's consequence as it puts load while fetching data from sheet.
I have changed code to fetch data only from a single column, but still needs to optimise it.

Any suggestion is welcomed...

Comment: You don't need to do all this calculation. Just pass "sheet1A1:Z1' and it will append at the next available line (starting on column A)

Comment: I set at "Sheet1!A:A" and it worked for me.

Comment: Neither `sheet1A1:Z1` nor `Sheet1!A:A` works

Answer (score 1):

Set the header row of sheet manually and always use the range of the header rows only

```
$range      = 'sheet1!A1:Z1';
```